# Как избежать foreach в foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу найти способа избежать вложения foreach в foreach. Было бы не критично, если бы в первом и втором должны перебираться тысячи строк.

Есть массив, полученный фетчем из БД:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [custom] => name1:::::value1;;;;;name2:::::value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [custom] => name3:::::value3;;;;;name4:::::value4;;;;;name5:::::value5
        )

)
```

Для дальнейшей работы с ним мне нужно преобразовать его к такому виду:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [custom] => name1:::::value1;;;;;name2:::::value2
            [name1] => value1
            [name2] => value2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12346
            [custom] => name3:::::value3;;;;;name4:::::value4;;;;;name5:::::value5
            [name3] => value3
            [name4] => value4
            [name5] => value5
        )

)
```

У меня получается это делать только дополнительным foreach после разделения на пары:

```
 foreach ($custom_fields_result as &$custom) {

    // Extract pairs
    $pairs = explode(";;;;;", $custom['custom']);

    // Extract values
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $pair = explode(":::::", $pair);
        $custom[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
    }
}
```

Но это плохо. Нужно обойтись без внутрненнего foreach, я уже голову сломал - не знаю как сделать.

Comment: почему плохо ?

Comment: если всегда такой формат разбивайте на 4 части сразу, preg_split например. получится массив из 4х элементов.

Comment: Я думаю плохо - потому что в исходном массиве больше 10 тыс. подмассивов. А внутри каждого подмассива  - сотни пар в поле custom

Одно дело пробежать 10 тыс., другое - в каждом из 10 тысяч пробегать еще сотню

Формат к сожалению не всегда такой. Кастомных полей может быть ноль или много - у каждого элемента по-разному

Comment: в любом случае у вас получается n*m перебор, какая разница  как его делать ?

Comment: а, я понял чего вам не нравится... ну разбейте вы сразу в  массив preg_split - четные (включая 0) элементы - ключи, нечетные - значения, но цикл все равно будет.

Comment: если уж совсем хочется без цикла, то  экстрагируйте ключи и значения в отдельные массивы и примените https://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php, только вряд-ли это будет быстрее

Comment: @silent-box, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно разбить вашу строку "типа без цикла"

```
$a="name3:::::value3;;;;;name4:::::value4;;;;;name5:::::value5";
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|;;;;;).+?(?=:::::)/',$a,$keys);
preg_match_all('/(?<=:::::).+?(?=$|;;;;;)/',$a,$values);
$all=array_combine($keys[0],$values[0]);
print_r($all);
```

http://ideone.com/R7b0cA

но это если уж очень хочется, практического смысла наверное нет.

Comment: внутри regexp движок-то, наверное, циклы не жалеет ; )

Comment: я знаю :) я поэтому в кавычках написал, там ещё и два раза строка проходится. но есть малюсенькая вероятность что два регекспа на микросекундочку быстрее phpшного цикла :), а array_combine() делает cow ссылки вместо копирования.

Answer (score 1):

если `name` и `values` не требуют urlencode, то можно было бы заменой:

```
$str = str_replace( ':::::', '=', $custom['custom']);
$str = str_replace( ';;;;;', '&', $str);
parse_str( $str, $custom); // в $custom допишутся пары значений
```

**upd.** раз в знаениях встречаются символы '`=`' и '`&`', и вопрос по-прежнему, «как избежать вложенного `foreach`?», то нужно просто один раз пройтись по строке слева направо, курсором натыкаясь то на один, то на другой разделитель ("`:::::`" | "`;;;;;`"), и по очереди вытаскивать либо key либо value, полагаясь на корректность формата в записях.

[ideone](http://ideone.com/cZdhNB)

```
$custom = array(
    'custom' => 'name1:::::val1;;;;;name2:::::val2;;;;;name3:::::val3',
);

$cursor = 0;
$isKey = TRUE; // true for Key, false for Value
$pos = 0;
$limit = mb_strlen( $custom['custom']);

while( TRUE) {
    $pos = mb_strpos( $custom['custom'], ($isKey ? ':::::' : ';;;;;'), $cursor);
    if( FALSE == $pos) {
        if( $isKey) break;
        else if( $cursor < $limit) $pos = $limit;
    }

    $sub = substr( $custom['custom'], $cursor, $pos - $cursor);
    if( $isKey) {
        $key = $sub;
    } else {
        $custom[ $key] = $sub;
    }

    $isKey = !$isKey;
    $cursor = $pos + 5; // 5 == length of separator
    if( $cursor >= $limit) break;
}

print_r( $custom);
```

Comment: вы бы ещё [parse_ini_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) предложили бы :)

Comment: Поля name и value могут содержать символы = и &. Иначе я бы мог еще в запросе к БД конкатенацию делать этими симоволами, но увы

Comment: просто в полях БД не надо хранить структуру, вот и всё.

Comment: погодите, вы сказали "конкатенация" ? может вам просто повернуть таблицу надо ?

Comment: Да, я конкатенирую при запросе из базы данных. Я пытался по-разному ее повернуть, не получается :) Вынес это в отдельный вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/354088